# Getting Forms to work correctly in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I can never seem to get Forms to work properly in Angular. I always add a `<form name="myform">` and then try to access it either in the template or in the controller using `$scope.myform` but it is always undefined! I can never seem to figure out exactly how these work.

Here is my code:

**Template**

```
<form name="o365form" novalidate>
          <ul class="formList">
                 <li>
                      <label>Office 365 Admin Username</label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.username" required/>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                      <label>Office 365 Admin Password</label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.password" required/>
                 </li>
          </ul>
</form>
```

Then I have this code in a function in my controller, but `o365form` is undefined...

**Controller**

```
if ($scope.o365form.$invalid) {
     return false;
} else {
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to [`ng-form` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) with this:

This is as simple as

```
<ng-form name="o365form">
          <ul class="formList">
                 <li>
                      <label>Office 365 Admin Username</label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.username" required/>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                      <label>Office 365 Admin Password</label>
                      <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.password" required/>
                 </li>
          </ul>
</ng-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-submit directive in form

```
<form name="o365form" ng-submit="submit(o365form)" novalidate>
      <ul class="formList">
             <li>
                  <label>Office 365 Admin Username</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.username" required/>
             </li>
             <li>
                  <label>Office 365 Admin Password</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="Master.Start.skAccount.password" required/>
             </li>
      </ul>
</form>
```

in controller

```
$scope.submit = function(o365form){
  if (o365form.$valid) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Example with $watch

```
<form name="o365form" form-valid novalidate>
      <ul class="formList">
             <li>
                  <label>Office 365 Admin Username</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="o365form.username" required/>
             </li>
             <li>
                  <label>Office 365 Admin Password</label>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="o365form.password" required/>
             </li>
      </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Directive

```
app.directive("formValid", function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs){
      $scope.$watch(attrs.name, function (isValid){
        if (isValid.$valid) alert("valid");
        else alert("not valid");

      }, true);
    }
  }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kahofadi/5/edit)

Comment: I'm a bigger fan of doing this declaratively in the view, ala `ng-submit="o365form.$valid && submit()"`. It will not call `submit()` if the form is invalid.

Comment: But what if I want the validation to occur all the time (with every $watch), not just when the user clicks a submit button?